# Counting graphs on n vertices by chromatic number

Tags: co.combinatorics

are there any results on the number of graphs on n vertices that has chromatic number=k ?

I mean how many graphs on n vertices has x(G)=2,x(G)=3,......,x(G)=n-1 ?

**update**:
infact equivalently, is there a way to count unique k-partite graphs?
after that to get x(G)=k, just subtract #k-partite-#(k-1)-partite.
I've been almost able to count number with x(G)=2 using a much easier way but the problem remains for k>=3

This is an expression I got for k=2 but needs to be verified:
$|\chi(G)=2|=n^{n-2}\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{n^{n-1}+n^{n-2}}{2}$

Comment: It seems that one should be able to count this for a given number N of vertices. compute a partition into different colors, and then compute how many ways edges can be formed between these partitions. The computation may be a bit messy, but seems doable. There may be some elegant way of getting it, of course, that I am not aware of.

Comment: @arnab: you are going to run into lots of double counting due to "random" isomorphisms between graphs, if I understand the original question correctly.

Comment: @alexander: absolutely. implicit in this process will be somehow quotienting with the isomorphic sets - because for every graph, you can get the size of its isomorphic class - but that's where it will get messy I think. 


Comment: So one might ask: Take a random $k$-partite graph on $n$ vertices for $n$ large. What is the asymptotic probability that the $k$-coloring provided by the $k$-partition is the only $k$-coloring up to permutation? If this isn't small then you have problems.

Comment: For the asymptotic answer, check out this paper http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/jchoco/clique/papersClique/bollobas.pdf by Bollobás.

Comment: You might consider labeled graphs instead. This gives a factor of roughly $n!$, since almost all graphs have no non-trivial automorphism.

Comment: Also, your expression for $\chi=2$ seems too small, since there are roughly $2^{n^2/4}$ bi-partite graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for chromatic number 2 can't quite be right, as it gives $3/2$ when $n=2$. [Number](http://oeis.org/A000683) of 2-colored labeled graphs on $n$ nodes is tabulated at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. The listing there agrees with the formula here for $n=3$ and $n=4$ but gives 360, not 375, for $n=5$. The page also references

F. Harary and E. M. Palmer, Graphical Enumeration, Academic Press, NY, 1973, p. 18, table 1.5.1, column 2 (divided by 2) and

R. C. Read, The number of k-colored graphs on labeled nodes, Canad. J. Math., 12 (1960), 410-414.